# Adding numpy arrays together produces NaN

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have two numpy matrices of size (1, 300). I'm trying to add these vectors together using:

```
v1 = np.array([size (1, 300)])
v2 = np.array([size (1, 300)])
composite_vector = v1+v2
```

However, when I add these vectors together, they sometimes produce NaN values in my array. None of the values stored in `v1` or `v2` is smaller than 1e-1010 or larger than 1e1010.

Below are the vectors and the sum of them - as you can see the calculation produces a NaN value on the fifth element of the composite vector

```
v1 = 
[ 6.71522716e-01  1.76001049e-01 -1.77978813e-02 -1.67818235e-01
   6.49510204e-01  1.17961152e-01  4.51483475e-01  4.16013189e-02
  -4.82717613e-01  5.27536713e+00  9.92400981e-02 -2.30960401e-01
  -3.97691269e-01  2.74559415e-01  7.95214763e-01 -1.46233688e-01
  -2.98350736e-01  3.84725958e+00  5.36448782e-01 -1.20091498e+00
  -1.08460359e+00 -3.67787614e-01 -4.18731943e-02 -6.53857927e-01
  -1.39055316e-01  2.29221790e-01  4.24631940e-01  4.17067428e-01
  -6.84043886e-01  5.67940523e-01  2.34671759e-01  2.39102578e-01
  -1.89179069e-01 -6.66960655e-01  2.38139940e-01 -1.04882286e+00
   1.94178799e-01 -2.40422038e-01  9.01451986e-02  3.09146941e-04
   1.95041243e-02  1.97037010e-01  7.86219505e-02  9.62363873e-02
   9.25215609e-01 -2.86541578e-01 -4.33041338e-01 -2.36510210e-01
   3.46118911e-01  3.42720211e-02 -8.02635945e-01  4.18728866e-01
   3.63454694e-01 -6.07591683e-01  8.22672708e-01  8.84082317e-02
   8.54813680e-03  2.91493231e-01  2.22120643e-01  3.49329288e-01
   8.84842966e-03 -1.26418871e+00  1.62532287e-01  6.01168144e-02
  -8.64796477e-01 -6.91210441e-02 -3.98214255e-01  4.32008657e-01
   7.12804026e-01  6.91372989e-01 -1.08363690e-01 -2.33505344e-01
  -5.72816040e-01  5.29473049e-01  1.03939761e-01 -7.80811720e-03
  -2.56789293e-01 -2.14936783e-01 -1.00462309e+00 -3.83582367e-01
   2.51725041e-01 -4.43524556e-01  7.16595950e-01  7.78096974e-01
  -4.01409164e-01 -1.30816502e-01 -1.06984675e+00  3.22993877e+00
   1.87815344e-02 -2.26687271e-01 -1.32080246e-01  7.00311549e-01
   6.34505315e-01  1.28521900e+00  8.59395075e-01 -4.17949413e-01
   2.89966636e-02  5.83748167e-01 -1.24921227e-01 -4.78061748e-01
   5.69711754e-01  5.15746681e-01 -3.87691692e-01  3.35399911e-01
   1.00697976e-01 -2.87296075e+00 -6.13980313e-01  2.46789730e-01
   1.57933660e-01 -2.42932108e-01 -3.15041399e-01 -8.40897248e-01
   7.43430997e-02  2.05458626e-01 -5.65759692e-01  9.74818766e-02
  -4.35647302e-01  5.60322888e-02 -2.73931884e-01 -2.78251058e-01
  -4.26278986e-01  2.16701739e-01 -8.35114416e-01  6.39869330e-01
   1.10430744e+00 -5.91260293e-02  3.87825220e-01 -8.21131697e-01
   1.09085958e+00 -3.00371453e-01  2.44440574e-01 -7.76353966e-01
  -8.71759272e-01  1.70474588e-02 -4.80593830e-01  5.24006281e-02
   3.25609347e-01 -8.92783845e-01 -4.17635581e-01 -3.12516503e-02
  -5.76108947e+00  1.53372454e-01  4.78484941e-01 -7.72789400e-03
  -5.77612015e-01 -7.94692251e-01  2.14087039e-02 -4.28472155e-01
   8.76712844e-01  3.33519094e-01  6.57425329e-01  4.87134758e-01
   4.86317206e-01 -4.17512911e-03 -1.17052626e-01  9.54824500e-03
  -2.40344323e-01 -1.47423235e+00  1.39372763e-01 -1.70445122e-01
  -8.22893795e-01 -1.70841943e-02  1.76048771e-01  6.01095172e-01
   7.84690027e-01 -7.27577307e-01  1.11934278e-01 -5.04793813e-02
   6.77075721e-02 -1.35203153e-01 -3.87213688e-01  7.42453817e-01
  -8.89065089e-02 -8.74378458e-02 -4.17313294e-01 -3.90219266e-01
   8.41722284e-02 -1.16647862e-01  1.89525895e-01  4.65315062e-01
  -3.21190489e-01 -5.37679592e-01  7.04364206e-01 -9.18682010e-01
  -6.72910508e-01 -1.40919466e-01 -1.73428821e-01  2.98641623e-01
   8.88176810e-01 -6.67454652e-03 -4.22649083e-01 -1.93917996e-01
   3.43307357e-01 -3.56192200e-01  5.35708779e-01 -1.86529241e-01
  -7.32596883e-01 -2.23535489e-01 -1.83481558e-01  8.56947826e-01
  -6.15763796e-01  1.77059797e-01  2.48534572e-01  1.79697378e-02
   1.34318457e-01  4.20626332e-01 -1.33121175e-01  6.30020052e-02
  -6.90048682e-01  1.92902852e-02 -1.52104445e+00  4.77676235e-01
  -1.66920717e-01 -1.40439998e+00  7.81913722e-01  1.68805902e+00
   4.78396498e-01  1.36025781e-02 -1.34203926e-01 -1.19133321e-01
  -5.95995560e-02 -1.20829535e-02  2.04598075e-01  5.16786201e-01
   1.34167913e-02 -4.28860176e-01 -2.90869919e-01  6.70302765e-01
   6.06854692e-01  6.21900816e-01 -4.62170240e-01 -6.65496003e-02
  -6.29163137e-01  4.71048152e-01  6.20925556e-01 -6.34684041e-01
  -1.41133795e-01 -4.99378357e-01  2.35631611e-01  4.78720872e-01
  -7.58400973e-01  4.57982188e-01 -5.74752837e-01  7.55223623e-01
   3.78572762e-01  1.44062649e+00 -1.55142213e-01 -2.44778357e-01
  -4.53624384e-01 -2.43692115e-01 -1.31339543e-01  3.40119197e-01
  -3.09576909e-01  1.66862076e-01 -4.53025788e-01  8.56795042e-01
   9.84747311e-01  5.77178384e-01 -2.23532175e-02  7.34853167e-01
   1.18959222e-01  1.01583900e+00  3.31537136e-01  7.48606591e-01
  -9.70502696e-02  6.64303014e-02  2.32263438e-01 -2.73252030e-01
  -9.37533164e-01  7.20819606e-01 -3.21591267e+00  5.39633073e-02
  -7.71392974e-01 -6.58556474e-01  4.54387919e-03 -5.93673432e-01
   3.46537664e-01  1.86176305e-01  7.09360854e-01  5.75872588e-01
   7.68726861e-01  1.15758114e-01  9.42207798e-02  4.16906164e-01
  -6.76095156e-01 -2.20385796e-01  2.02536462e-01  4.65010706e-01
   1.32890373e-01 -4.00648732e-01 -7.25661369e-01  3.18065435e-01
  -2.42473208e-01  5.63133505e-01 -4.16106067e-01  4.13314546e-01
   3.84893622e-02  2.70658952e-01  1.02031836e-03  5.96846916e-01]

v2 = 
 [ 6.80840974e-01  1.08222457e+00  1.89015904e-01 -5.08703661e-01
   2.41635456e+00  3.45187727e-03  3.17377068e-01 -1.33426369e+00
  -4.09772869e-01  9.59687348e+00 -6.62706033e-01  5.18800816e-02
  -2.41171847e-01  3.46237607e-02 -2.13357601e-02  4.41735274e-01
   5.03468092e-02  4.56489233e+00 -8.02953711e-01 -8.99890657e-01
   2.43052538e-02 -5.87027236e-01  1.44889726e-01 -9.24025238e-01
   1.99596186e-01 -2.29879858e-01 -1.02551949e+00  9.07673529e-01
   5.23291807e-01 -2.33934075e-03  2.29645110e-01 -2.75019081e-01
  -2.60325444e-01 -4.55149302e-01 -9.17764818e-02 -2.19489198e-01
  -6.55176463e-01  7.74218311e-01 -1.35844554e-01 -3.07842242e-02
   7.87439297e-01  3.46119592e-01  6.23998791e-03  7.69885175e-01
   8.95925693e-01  9.73564991e-01  6.62703942e-01 -3.66244032e-01
  -8.58154269e-02 -5.05544388e-01 -1.10951055e+00  3.95863112e-02
   3.88151889e-01  7.10091545e-01 -5.48397948e-01 -2.28873915e-01
   2.71538325e-01 -1.36772090e-01  1.99539744e-01 -7.44140037e-01
  -5.21677930e-01 -1.27869547e+00 -1.20050004e-01  2.51207745e-01
  -9.28238406e-01 -1.46889219e+00 -5.02986318e-01  7.94671242e-01
   4.28721608e-01  8.19892559e-01 -4.64599904e-01  3.53850354e-02
   5.24377418e-02 -3.00924515e-01 -1.01081805e-02 -5.16774284e-01
  -3.58204136e-01  1.08205832e+00 -6.02301071e-01  7.46438447e-01
   5.70911976e-01  3.50303550e-01 -1.09521374e-01  6.79268247e-01
  -5.98512002e-01  6.23896335e-01  6.66320262e-01  1.56125277e+00
  -3.46441715e-01 -5.35648258e-01 -1.25729273e+00 -6.87203370e-01
   6.92535645e-01  5.37416469e-01  1.06842566e+00 -1.26931941e+00
   1.13688784e+00  9.97466835e-01 -7.97326249e-01 -2.96736817e-01
   1.63387611e-01 -9.49033803e-01  2.34477043e-01  7.78336064e-02
   2.57997866e-01 -2.63031541e+00  1.22107316e+00 -2.53530167e-01
   8.98693812e-01 -5.56649061e-01  1.58885792e-01 -1.21601806e+00
  -2.70696640e-01  2.02899849e-01  6.78179590e-01  2.83968075e-01
   8.36400175e-01  5.39272078e-01 -1.16782952e+00  6.00040074e-01
   2.45945316e-01  6.83180027e-01 -1.86759203e-01  1.21131758e-02
   3.43630549e-01  6.53674275e-01  7.53259926e-01 -3.30195450e-01
   9.41805335e-01  8.70533698e-01  7.63376585e-01 -1.01149009e+00
   3.09560738e-01  2.10269890e-01  1.38180832e+00  6.71481983e-01
  -5.78927661e-01  2.94072321e-03  2.37464768e-01 -1.08133251e+00
  -1.10113370e+01  4.30279495e-02  1.56820923e-01 -2.04289891e-01
  -8.64133349e-01 -1.50918914e-01  9.03650613e-01 -6.91856625e-01
   2.92949418e-01 -1.08226561e+00 -2.13742531e-01 -1.12288442e-01
  -3.70377501e-01  8.34795704e-01  9.98569989e-01 -7.67004536e-01
   3.62306936e-01 -1.85033053e+00  6.48983885e-01 -1.36072374e+00
   2.08188856e-01 -5.68321475e-01  9.12867156e-01 -4.13704124e-01
   9.22410181e-01 -5.67607224e-01 -6.96386956e-01 -9.93721031e-01
  -5.36995981e-01  2.13035466e-01  4.86712846e-01  3.38213607e-02
  -3.61313901e-01 -1.10207830e+00 -3.27086710e-01 -7.59134999e-01
  -5.75848096e-01 -7.42727052e-03  2.66385559e-01 -7.03415170e-01
   3.21424244e-01 -1.20882045e-01  1.09473436e+00  2.03045310e-01
  -2.65840843e-01  4.93563807e-01 -6.82739358e-01  2.73103496e-01
   4.31449637e-01 -9.24971296e-01  7.15496726e-02 -1.92146460e-01
  -8.60685006e-01 -8.39486291e-01 -7.92146324e-01  5.19405275e-02
  -6.95424106e-01 -5.69414062e-01  6.02244138e-01 -2.47432487e-01
  -4.34355595e-01 -1.07837283e-01  1.32522011e-02  1.59216576e-01
   6.02156725e-01 -6.45504831e-01 -2.94020553e-01 -1.30434350e-01
   7.04957346e-01 -6.86732803e-01 -1.27494802e+00  1.65109250e+00
  -2.71356047e-01 -4.17883361e-01  1.00949544e-01  1.44076467e+00
   3.13068775e-01 -8.28959271e-01  9.09669771e-01  1.11012771e+00
  -3.72678792e-01  2.79221355e-01 -3.44947677e-01  8.82469683e-02
   2.25149028e-01  1.41286211e-01 -2.65700271e-01 -1.83076371e-01
   1.11346852e+00  4.21954349e-01 -4.47518755e-01 -4.39430828e-01
  -5.62444557e-02  3.81211454e-01 -1.80647857e-02 -4.52478832e-01
  -8.95624682e-01 -3.12069496e-02 -4.11403767e-01  2.53328356e-01
  -1.07857434e+00  1.68821388e-01 -5.01107505e-01  3.00803318e-01
  -1.57732102e-01  1.07451440e+00 -5.55646353e-01  7.88619872e-02
  -2.29958531e-01 -5.48542802e-01  1.43211507e-02  2.74252550e-01
  -4.90469476e-01  6.82045617e-01  3.79044290e-01  8.44461500e-01
   1.53178156e-01 -3.07160458e-01 -1.93368721e-01  5.43589889e-01
  -9.42966710e-02  3.93280542e-01  3.47361914e-01  4.83696428e-01
  -2.64183397e-01 -8.22343061e-01 -2.31023552e-01 -3.10740942e-01
  -5.45774631e-01  1.27622189e+00 -4.03592953e+00  8.62728572e-02
  -4.18462265e-01  2.98368017e-03  4.98270962e-01 -9.28206671e-01
   5.04501998e-01 -8.67197957e-01  1.90088416e-01  6.24125131e-01
   4.26296185e-01  4.73721744e-03 -5.93253737e-01 -1.77936572e-01
  -3.63077476e-01 -1.59699360e-01  1.53916423e+00  3.04897348e-01
   5.67107857e-02 -6.42787840e-02 -3.53969141e-01 -4.93914781e-01
   8.80186645e-01  1.14711054e+00  3.20992951e-01  7.64317893e-01
   3.62343249e-01 -3.20556623e-01  4.28908955e-01  6.28184980e-01]

composite_vector = 
[ 1.35236369e+000  1.25822562e+000  1.71218023e-001 -6.76521896e-001
   3.06586476e+000              nan  7.68860543e-001              nan
  -8.92490482e-001 -1.85638866e+304 -2.06238619e+304 -6.89661244e+303
               nan  3.57470595e+046  7.73879003e-001  2.95501586e-001
   5.07317565e+241  8.41215191e+000 -2.66504929e-001  3.39213101e+191
  -1.06029833e+000 -9.54814850e-001 -1.89390109e+064 -1.57788316e+000
   6.05408697e-002 -6.58067902e-004 -6.00887550e-001  1.32474096e+000
  -2.56376661e+060  5.65601182e-001  4.64316869e-001 -3.59165032e-002
  -4.49504513e-001 -1.12210996e+000  5.85447606e+197 -1.26831206e+000
  -4.60997664e-001  1.29920148e+126 -4.56993554e-002 -3.04750773e-002
   5.91187615e+218  5.43156602e-001  8.48619384e-002  8.66121562e-001
   1.82114130e+000  6.87023413e-001  2.57135263e+186 -6.02754242e-001
   2.60303484e-001 -4.71272367e-001 -1.91214650e+000  4.58315177e-001
   5.24201752e+101  1.02499862e-001  2.74274760e-001 -1.40465683e-001
   2.80086462e-001  1.54721141e-001  4.21660387e-001 -3.94810749e-001
  -5.12829500e-001 -2.54288418e+000  4.24822827e-002  3.11324559e-001
  -5.79326868e+118 -1.53801323e+000 -9.01200573e-001 -2.08465810e+139
   1.14152563e+000  1.51126555e+000 -5.72963594e-001 -1.98120308e-001
  -5.20378298e-001  2.28548534e-001  9.38315809e-002 -5.24582401e-001
  -6.96062746e+156  8.67121537e-001 -1.60692416e+000  9.27760080e+165
   8.22637017e-001 -9.32210062e-002 -4.81349020e+188  1.45736522e+000
  -9.99921166e-001  2.68337274e+206 -4.03526489e-001  4.79119154e+000
  -3.27660181e-001 -7.62335529e-001 -1.38937298e+000  8.58652793e+060
   1.32704096e+000  1.82263547e+000  6.35073515e+162 -1.68726882e+000
   1.16588450e+000 -2.35529430e+186 -9.22247476e-001 -7.74798565e-001
   7.33099365e-001 -4.33287122e-001 -1.53214649e-001 -1.31792435e+293
   3.58695842e-001 -5.50327616e+000 -6.83059727e+128 -6.74043685e-003
   1.05662747e+000  8.17490799e+256 -1.56155607e-001 -2.05691531e+000
  -1.96353540e-001  4.08358475e-001  1.12419898e-001  3.81449952e-001
   4.00752873e-001  5.95304367e-001 -1.44176140e+000  3.21789016e-001
  -1.80333670e-001  8.99881766e-001 -1.02187362e+000  6.51982506e-001
   1.44793799e+000  5.94548246e-001  1.14108515e+000 -1.15132715e+000
   2.03266492e+000  5.70162245e-001  1.00781716e+000 -1.78784406e+000
  -5.62198534e-001  2.27317349e-001  9.01214490e-001  7.23882611e-001
  -2.53318314e-001 -8.89843122e-001 -1.80170813e-001 -1.11258416e+000
  -1.67724265e+001  1.96400404e-001  6.35305864e-001 -2.12017785e-001
  -1.44174536e+000 -9.45611165e-001  9.25059317e-001 -1.12032878e+000
   1.16966226e+000 -7.48746516e-001  4.43682798e-001  3.74846316e-001
   1.15939705e-001  8.30620575e-001  8.81517363e-001 -7.57456291e-001
   1.21962613e-001 -3.32456288e+000  7.88356648e-001 -1.53116886e+000
  -6.14704939e-001 -5.85405669e-001  1.08891593e+000  1.87391048e-001
   1.70710021e+000 -1.29518453e+000 -5.84452678e-001 -1.04420041e+000
  -4.69288409e-001  7.78323131e-002  9.94991581e-002  7.76275178e-001
  -4.50220410e-001 -1.18951615e+000 -7.44400004e-001 -1.14935426e+000
  -4.91675868e-001 -1.24075132e-001  4.55911454e-001 -2.38100108e-001
   2.33755475e-004 -6.58561637e-001  1.79909857e+000 -7.15636700e-001
  -9.38751351e-001  3.52644341e-001 -8.56168179e-001  5.71745119e-001
   1.31962645e+000 -9.31645843e-001 -3.51099410e-001 -3.86064456e-001
  -5.17377649e-001 -1.19567849e+000 -2.56437545e-001 -1.34588713e-001
  -1.42802099e+000 -7.92949551e-001  4.18762580e-001  6.09515339e-001
  -1.05011939e+000  6.92225141e-002  2.61786773e-001  1.77186314e-001
   7.36475182e-001 -2.24878499e-001 -4.27141728e-001 -6.74323448e-002
   1.49086644e-002 -6.67442518e-001 -2.79599247e+000  2.12876874e+000
  -4.38276764e-001 -1.82228334e+000  8.82863266e-001  3.12882369e+000
   7.91465273e-001 -8.15356693e-001  7.75465845e-001  9.90994389e-001
  -4.32278348e-001  2.67138402e-001 -1.40349602e-001  6.05033169e-001
   2.38565819e-001 -2.87573965e-001 -5.56570190e-001  4.87226394e-001
   1.72032321e+000  1.04385516e+000 -9.09688995e-001 -5.05980428e-001
  -6.85407592e-001  8.52259606e-001  6.02860770e-001 -1.08716287e+000
  -1.03675848e+000 -5.30585307e-001 -1.75772156e-001  7.32049228e-001
  -1.83697531e+000  6.26803576e-001 -1.07586034e+000  1.05602694e+000
   2.20840660e-001  2.51514089e+000 -7.10788566e-001 -1.65916370e-001
  -6.83582915e-001 -7.92234917e-001 -1.17018392e-001  6.14371747e-001
  -8.00046385e-001  8.48907693e-001 -7.39814976e-002  1.70125654e+000
   1.13792547e+000  2.70017926e-001 -2.15721938e-001  1.27844306e+000
   2.46625510e-002  1.40911955e+000  6.78899050e-001  1.23230302e+000
  -3.61233667e-001 -7.55912760e-001  1.23988640e-003 -5.83992972e-001
  -1.48330780e+000  1.99704150e+000 -7.25184220e+000  1.40236164e-001
  -1.18985524e+000 -6.55572794e-001  5.02814841e-001 -1.52188010e+000
   8.51039662e-001 -6.81021652e-001  8.99449270e-001  1.19999772e+000
   1.19502305e+000  1.20495332e-001 -4.99032957e-001  2.38969592e-001
  -1.03917263e+000 -3.80085156e-001  1.74170069e+000  7.69908054e-001
   1.89601159e-001 -4.64927516e-001 -1.07963051e+000 -1.75849346e-001
   6.37713437e-001  1.71024405e+000 -9.51131157e-002  1.17763244e+000
   4.00832611e-001 -4.98976713e-002  4.29929273e-001  1.22503190e+000]
```

Why is it producing a NaN value and how do I prevent this from occurring.

NOTE: The vectors are not normalised and normalisation does not seem to prevent this from occurring.

Edit: Added full numpy arrays

Comment: share input data to check where the nan shows up

Comment: What is the actual range of your data?

Comment: Can't quite reproduce your output, `-1.76642545e-01 + (-0.95480421)` returns the expected `-1.13144676` (inside numpy arrays of course).

Comment: @QuangHoang +1, the behaviour not reproducible. Please check the code that generates these (1,300) shaped arrays and see if they are not generating nans accidentally.